# Random IBM MQ XMS error 2195 on publishing to topic

Tags: c#, ibm-mq, xms

I am having this random issue while publishing JSON string messages to IBM MQ topic. It happens so randomly all the time. I am not sure how to pinpoint the issue. This is happening since I switched to SSL Channel.

IBM.XMS.dll version I am using is 8.0.0.6. Following is the code snippet and exception details:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            XMSFactoryFactory factoryFactory = XMSFactoryFactory.GetInstance(XMSC.CT_WMQ);

            IConnectionFactory connectionFactory = factoryFactory.CreateConnectionFactory();
            Console.WriteLine("Connection Factory created.");

            connectionFactory.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, "MQ_TX_MGR");
            connectionFactory.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CONNECTION_NAME_LIST, "10.10.10.10(1414)");
            connectionFactory.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CHANNEL, "CL.SVRCONN");

            connectionFactory.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, XMSC.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
            connectionFactory.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT_OPTIONS, XMSC.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT);
            connectionFactory.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT_TIMEOUT, 3); 
            connectionFactory.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_SSL_KEY_REPOSITORY, "*SYSTEM");
            connectionFactory.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_SSL_CIPHER_SPEC, "MYCipherSpec");

            mqConnection = connectionFactory.CreateConnection();
            Console.WriteLine("Connection created.");

            session = mqConnection.CreateSession(false, AcknowledgeMode.AutoAcknowledge);
            Console.WriteLine("Session created.");


            IDestination destination = session.CreateTopic("topic://TOPIC/NAME"); // destinationName
            Console.WriteLine("Destination created.");

            // create producer
            IMessageProducer producer = session.CreateProducer(destination);  
            IMessage outbound = null;
            outbound = session.CreateTextMessage("Long JSON String");
            producer.Send(outbound);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Program waiting for message:");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
```

Exception:

> Stack Trace:
>   at IBM.WMQ.MQFAP.NmqiConnect(String name,
>   NmqiConnectOptions pNmqiConnectOpts, MQConnectOptions cno, Hconn
>   parentHconn, Phconn pHconn, Int32& compCode, Int32& reason,
>   ManagedHconn rcnHconn)    
> at IBM.WMQ.MQFAP.NmqiConnect(String
>   pQMgrName, NmqiConnectOptions pNmqiConnectOpts, MQConnectOptions
>   pConnectOpts, Hconn parentHconn, Phconn pHconn, Int32& pCompCode,
>   Int32& pReason)    
> at
>   IBM.XMS.Client.WMQ.WmqSession..ctor(WmqConnection connection,
>   AcknowledgeMode ackMode, XmsPropertyContext properties)    
> at
>   IBM.XMS.Client.WMQ.WmqConnection.CreateSession(XmsPropertyContext
>   properties, AcknowledgeMode ackMode)    
> at
>   IBM.XMS.Client.Impl.XmsConnectionImpl.CreateSession(Boolean
>   transacted, AcknowledgeMode ackMode)

Comment: What Cipherspec are you using?

Comment: TLS 1.0, Secure Hash Algorithm, 128-bit AES encryption

Comment: Can you start a looping trace and then stop it once you encounter the problem again?  I would send this to IBM via PMR to have them look into the cause.

Comment: Can you try by increasing the Reconnect timeout.Certainly looks to be a  problem,but just to make sure that is not causing the problem